# Android: Create a new folder and change it's permissions

Tags: android, directory, internal-storage, folder-permissions

I have an app. I want this app to create a new folder which can only be opened by this app and no one else. I want this folder outside the application internal storage, so that it is visible in file manager, but it can't be opened because of folder permission (rwx --- ---).

So is there a way create a folder, make this app its owner, and change its permission so that only this app can open it and no one else (not even file manager or gallery etc.)

Comment: what kind of app is this?

Comment: I wanted to make a folder locker, but since I can't lock the folders directly, I wanted to create my own folders, and allow user to move data to these folders.

Answer (score 0):

In order to change file's permission. First you should get root ownership of the device.
Which means YOU HAVE TO ROOT the DEVICE!

[Android Application SandBox](http://developer.android.com/intl/ko/training/articles/security-tips.html)

Comment: And what if the app is system app instead of third party app?

Comment: Doesn't matter. whether it is system app or not, it needs root privilege. Only way to get root privilege is ROOTING the device and create app for root oriented like Root Manager app.

Comment: I understand that this requires root, but I'd like to know (and it would answer the question) of how to create a new folder and change access permissions. I can create a folder within /data/data/com.termux using a root file manager, but even after changing permissions with the tool provided by the app, com.termux has no rights to view or modify the content of the folder.